# Паттерн "Рукоятки" или "Ручки" на С

Tags: c, структуры-данных, динамические-структуры

недавно на просторах интернета заметил упоминание о паттерне для языка Си "Рукоятка" или "Ручка". Насколько я его понял, что необходимо возвращать из функции не саму структуру, а ее дескриптор(что-то похожее с инкапсуляцией). Тому примером может послужить функции CreateThread(...), CreateMutex(..) и т.д.

И вот с этим у меня возникли небольшие недопонимания... Допустим я отдаю int-овый дескриптор клиенту, но где-то же мне его нужно хранить, ведь так? Придется чтоли создавать в этом файле массив или список структур?

К примеру можно взять вот такую вот структуру(обертка над потоком):

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_t tid;
    const char* name;
    int prioritet;
} thread_t;
```

И взять к примеру ряд операций с ней:

```
thread_t* create_thread(const char* name);
void run(thread_t* thread, ...);
void detach(thread_t* thread);
void join(thread_t* thread);
void destroy(thread_t** thread, ...);
```

Вот как будет выглядеть этот паттерны на этом примере? Хотелось бы, чтобы мне четко объяснили как это все работает, да и вообще как это принято делать, а также привели пример. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос не ясен, в функции выделяете память на эту структуру и отдаете ссылку на эту память, все стандартно. Можно сделать структуру `static`на эту структуру внутри функции, и отдавать ссылку на нее, не мультитредно и полно разных камней..

Comment: Это понятно... Но суть в том, что пользователю нужно предоставить набор функций над дескриптором структуры, а не над самой структурой, чтобы он ничего случайно там не поломал...

Comment: Делать ее тупедефом типом `void*`, внутри всех функций кастить войд в структуру, структура получается закрытой.

Comment: @VladimirBalun Как этот паттерн называется на английском?

Comment: @zed, lol, по английский это так и надывается «handle», только вот называть это «паттерном» как-то слишком громко...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть два варианта.

Да, заводим себе глобальный массив и храним там все. В этом случае по int дескриптору можно сделать все, что нужно. Ничего необычного. Типичный пример - дескрипторы в линукс.

Плюсы:

- учет ресурсов
- можно аккуратно самому почистить память
- можно даже по сети передавать

Минусы:

- нужен глобальный массив или что то в этом стиле
- лишнее кодирование:)
- ушлый пользователь может попытаться "перебирать дескрипторы"

Второй вариант - в качестве дескриптора возвращаем просто указатель, который кастован к `void*`.

Плюсы:

- легко кодится

Минусы:

- легко сделать доступ не по тому адресу
- пользователь может "угадать структуру" и извлечь данные.

Comment: Структуру, я как понимаю, нужно будет тогда помещать в .с файл? Правильно?

Comment: наверно. Все зависит от того, что именно Вы хотите сделать